# How to Calculate Linear and Rotational Velocity from Multiple Thrusters in Space

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity, space

I'm trying to simulate space thrusters in Unity. If I have a spherical ship in space (assume no drag/gravity around) with two thrusters at positions p1 and p2 in relation to the ships center of mass point Cp, how do I calculate the direction of motion and the angular velocity of the ship based upon the forces applied in direction $v_1$ and $v_2$? I assume I'm applying $Nm$ force in direction $v_1$ and $v_2$ and given mass $M$ and their respective locations from $C_p$, this creates angular and linear velocities. Is there a simple equation for these two things? I imagine if you calculate the linear and angular velocities for the thrusters individually that you can simply add them for the final answer? I'm a noob to this stuff, but hoping for some simple equations without too huge a story.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your 'go to' equations are Newton's Second Law for translation and rotation.

**For translation:**

If an $x$-axis is aligned with $v_1$ and $v_2$, then (in the absence of gravity):

$$\Sigma F_x=m\ddot{x}\tag{1}$$

where $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2}=\ddot{x}$ is the *translational acceleration*.

**For rotation:**

$$\Sigma \tau=I\alpha\tag{2}$$

where $\tau$ are the torques about Cp, $I$ is the moment of inertia about Cp and $\alpha=\frac{\mathrm{d}^2\theta}{\mathrm{d}t^2}$ is the *angular acceleration*.

$(1)$ and $(2)$ are ordinary differential equations of motion, which when solved provide a full description of the dynamic kinematics of the object. These ODEs will need initial conditions ($t=0$) for a full solution to be obtained.

Comment: Being the n00b that I am, I have no idea where any of my variables fit into any of those variables :-P. How would I apply this to the provided variables?

Comment: Hi. The LHS of (1) is simply the sum of the thrusts (as forces), which is equal to the mass times the acceleration. In (2), each torque $\tau$ equals the thrust times the radius of the spaceship, these torques need then to be summed up. Unfortunately I can't really include a tutorial on ODEs.